# watchkit extension not starting

Tags: watchkit, xcode-6.2

I cannot start iOS Watch App on simulator. Installed latest Beta 6.2 on Yosemite

1) I create a single view based application,

2) Add App Watch target

3) Extension and Watch App automatically created

4) Run App and start simulator and enable Apple Watch simulator

5) Switch Scheme to app Watch App and start Run

Xcode status bar showing Running App...... and never jumping to second step of

Running App extension, so nothing is showing on Apple Watch!!

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Select you "... Watch App" Run it on iPhone 5 simulator and higher
(watch simulator not working with iPhone 4s)

**2.** Go to Hardware > External Displays > Select one of Watch external displays.

As a result you should see the log on the console from your `WKInterfaceController` `WathcKit` Extension

Comment: Try creating new project. Create new project. Add watch App target, select watch App schema and run it. This should work

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem. I created a new project and added WatchKit extension in Xcode 6.2 beta 4 with WatchKit. I tried all ways mentioned in other answers but still failed to let watch app run in the simulator. Finally, I made it work.

My steps:

1. Delete the containing app in the iPhone simulator.
2. Clean your project in Xcode.
3. Do not run the containing app, run the WatchKit app from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**1.** Dont run main target, run watch extension target. you can find below attachment, so that you can get an idea

**2.** Go to Hardware > External Displays > Select one of Watch external displays