# Apple watchkit simulator not available

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I just started working on Apple's WatchKit on Xcode7. For running app, I tried to enable external display from simulator but there is no option for Apple Watch. Below is the screen shot when I tried to enable external display:

[image]

I also tried to find out some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005132/running-apple-watch-in-ios-simulator-issue?noredirect=1#), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283431/watchkit-extension-not-starting) but could not get success.

Any idea or suggestion in order to resolve this issue would be great.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 7, one would need to click on menu tab:

***Xcode*** ->
***Open Developer Tool*** - and subsequently -> ***(Simulator) Watch***.